# Prove an isomorphism via abstract nonsense

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Suppose we are working in an abelian category and we have a commutative diagram with exact rows

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1em\xrightarrow{#1}\kern-1em}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
0 & \;\;\ra{} & A_1 & \ra{} & A_2 & \;\;\ra{} & A_3 & \;\;\ra{} & A_4 & \;\;\ra{} & 0 \\
 & & \da{\;f_1} & & \da{\;f_2} & & \da{\;f_3} & & \da{\;f_4} & & \\
0 & \;\;\ra{} & B_1 & \;\;\ra{} & B_2 & \;\;\ra{} & B_3 & \;\;\ra{} & B_4 & \;\ra{} & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

with $f_1$, $f_3 $ and $ f_4$ isomorphisms. Can we then conclude (by diagram chasing maybe?) that $f_2$ is also an isomorphism?

Comment: This follows trivially from five lemma,

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the five lemma?

Comment: To add a little bit more to the last two comments - add two extra zeros on the left, and an isomorphism between the two you already drew. Then you can use the five lemma.

Comment: Interesting to know that `\uparrow` and `\downarrow` can be used for `\left` and `\right`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing it out, it's indeed an immediate application of the [5 lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma). As Matt said, just add a pair of zeros on the left to get the commutative diagram

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
0 & \;\;\ra{} \;& 0 & \;\ra{} & A_1 & \;\;\ra{} & A_2 & \;\;\ra{} & A_3 & \;\;\ra{} & A_4 & \;\;\ra{} & 0 \\
 & & \da{\;f_0} & & \da{\;f_1} & & \da{\;f_2} & & \da{\;f_3} & & \da{\;f_4} & & \\
0 & \;\;\ra{} \;& 0 & \;\ra{} & B_1 & \;\;\ra{} & B_2 & \;\;\ra{} & B_3 & \;\;\ra{} & B_4 & \;\ra{} & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

Now it's clear that the five lemma implies that $f_2$ is an isomorphism.